# Controller being called N times when coming back to a same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new on AngularJS and I have a problem. I am doing a SinglePageApplication with currently two views. On the main view I have a button which prints "toto". However, when I switch to the second view then come back to the first one, it will print it twice (then three times, four times... for every switch between views).

Can't figure out why since it seems I call my controller at only one place. Here is my code :

**Page template :**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<section id="container" class="">
    <% include partials/header %>
    <% include partials/aside %>
    <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper">   
            <ui-view ></ui-view>
        </section>
    <footer>
        <% include partials/footer %>
    </footer>
    </section>

</section>
```

**HomeView :**

```
<div class="button">
   <span>Button</span>
   <div >
      <a ng-click="test()" >&#xF011;</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
controller('MonitorCtrl', function ($scope, socket, stateService) {
      $scope.data = stateService.get(); //init service saving state
      $scope.test= function() {
          console.log('toto');
      };
});
```

**Routes:**

```
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "partials/home.ejs",
        controller: "MonitorCtrl"
    })
    .state("configuration", {
        url:"/config",
        templateUrl: "partials/config.ejs",
        controller: "ConfigCtrl"
    });
  }).
```

**Service:**

```
factory('stateService', function() {
   var data = {} ;
   data = "test";

   return {
       get: function() {
           return data;
       }
   };
});
```

**Aside (menu) :**

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">                
      <li class="">
          <a class="" ui-sref="home">
              <i class="icon_desktop"></i>
              <span>Monitoring</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="" ui-sref="configuration">
              <i class="icon_cog"></i>
              <span>Configurations</span>
          </a>
      </li>
```

If someone has an idea I would be grateful.

Comment: Any working example?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem some months ago while using AngularJs with ui-router. The controller was called multiple times and the number of times increased as I navigated more between states. The solution was to simply update the ui-router which had a bug in it. So upgrade the ui-router module and let us know if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Made a npm update but it seems no update was required. Got 
angular-ui-router@0.4.2
  `-- angular@1.6.4

So problem not solved.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the output is cumulative? In chrome, it counts the number of times that `console.log()` outputs the **exact same output without any other output** as a single line with a count, but that doesn't mean it ran it that many times for *one* button press.  http://plnkr.co/edit/k9AN6uPWqEZBfjDc1iAk?p=preview.  Outputting something in between breaks up the calls http://plnkr.co/edit/MCmXBcMiXjuOWvkpeunS?p=preview

Comment: Yes I'm sure. If I click several times i'll have 1,2,3,4 outputs so it's ok one by one. But if I switch views like I explained and click again several times I'll get 6,8,10...